# Ambiguity in the definition of "locally finiteness of a collection of subsets of a topological space".

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

From the book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", by John M. Lee, page 9:

> **Definition.** Let $M$ be a topological space. 
>   A collection $\mathcal{X}$ 
>   of subsets of $M$ 
>   is said to be 
>   **locally finite**
>   if each point of $M$ 
>   has a neighborhood 
>   that intersects 
>   at most finitely many
>   of the sets in 
>   $\mathcal{X}$. 
>   Given a cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $M$; 
>   another cover $\mathcal{V}$ 
>   is called a **refinement** of $\mathcal{U}$ 
>   if for each $V \in \mathcal{V}$ 
>   there exists some $U \in \mathcal{U}$ 
>   such that $V \subseteq U$. 
>   We say that 
>   $M$ is **paracompact** if 
>   every open cover of $M$ admits an open, 
>   locally finite refinement.

---

**Claim.**  Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a 
*locally finite*
collection of
subsets of $M$, 
and let 
$$x \in 
\bigcup_{ \mathcal{U} \in \mathcal{X} } \mathcal{U} 
\subseteq M$$
Then $x$ belongs to 
at most finitely many 
$\mathcal{U} \in \mathcal{X}$.

**Proof.** 
Suppose on contrary that 
there exists an infinite set $I$ of indexes;
such that
$x \in \mathcal{U}_i$ 
for every $i \in I$.  But notice that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects with 
each $\mathcal{U}_i$;
which contradicts the assumption that
$\mathcal{X}$ is 
locally finite.

---

I myself suspect in the truth of the above claim.
But if this is true, 
then we can give an 
equivalent definition of 
"locally finite" 
as follows:

> **[Definition.]**  A collection $\mathcal{X}$ 
>   of subsets of $M$ 
>   is said to be 
>   **locally finite** 
>   if each point of $M$ 
>   is contained in at most finitely many
>   of the sets in
>   $\mathcal{X}$.

The above 
fake-definition
looks like it is much simpler to understand; at least to me.

- If my proof is true, then why didn't Lee use this other definition?
- If my proof is false, where is the bug in my proof? Can you give me a counter-example, i.e. a collection $\mathcal{X}$ of subsets of $M$, such that: each point of $M$ has a neighbourhood that intersects at most finitely many of the sets in $\mathcal{X}$, but there exists a point $x$ which is contained in infinitely many sets in $\mathcal{X}$?

---

**In short:**  Can you give an example of a topological space $M$ and a collection $\mathcal{X}$ of subsets of $M$, such that each point of $M$ 
has a neighbour that intersects at most finitely many of the sets in $\mathcal{X}$, but there exists a point $x$ which is contained in infinitely many sets in $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: Your definition is that of a "point-finite" family. That is a weaker condition than being locally finite [Lee proves that local finiteness implies point-finiteness; or is that your proof?].

Comment: Surely any neighbourhood $U$ of such an $x$ intersects infinitely many of the sets in $\mathcal{X}$ since it contains $x$ which lies in infinitely many of the sets in $\mathcal{X}$. Such a pair $(M\mathcal{X})$ cannot exist.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer♦ , this is my proof. It is obvious that every fimily with the "point-finiteness" property must hsve the " local finiteness" property. But could you give me a counter-example of a family which has the "local finiteness" property without the "point-finiteness" property?

Comment: You're claiming you have an "equivalent" definition. In order to prove that A and B are equivalent, it's not enough to prove "if A then B", you also have to prove "if B then A", which you have not done.

Comment: In $\mathbb R$ the family $$\{(\frac12,1),(\frac13,\frac12),(\frac14,\frac13),\dots,(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n),\dots\}$$ is point  finite but not locally finite.

Comment: No, quite the other way round. Every locally finite family is point-finite, but not all point-finite families are locally finite. For example $$\mathcal{X} = \{(-1,1)\} \cup \Biggl\{ \biggl(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n-1}\biggr) : n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1\}\Biggr\}$$ is a point-finite family that isn't locally finite. (The space is $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.)

Comment: @bof In my original post it is clear that I believe  that there is a bug in my proof. Also notice that the converse is trivial.

Comment: No. What you proved is the trivial direction: "if a family is locally finite, then it is point finite". The other direction, "if a family is point finite then it is locally finite" is the nontrivial direction, which you did not prove, and it is false: It is quite easy to come up with point finite families (in fact, pairwise disjoint families) which are not locally finite.

Comment: @bof ; yes you are right; I am mistaken

Comment: @Daniel Fischer♦ ; If I am not mistaken every neighborhood of $0$; intersects with infinitely many of the above intervals.

Comment: @bof ; If I am not mistaken every neighborhood of $0$; intersects with infinitely many of the above intervals.

Comment: Yes, that's the ***point***. The collection is ***not*** locally finite, but it ***is*** point finite: every point $x$ belongs to at most finitely many (in fact, at most one) of the sets in the collection. Therefore, the two properties are ***not equivalent***.

Comment: @bof ;  I get it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Related discussion on meta: [Should the overuse of colored text be discouraged?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26848) (Since your question was mentioned there as an example, I thought it might be a good idea to let you know about this discussion.)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak ; Thank you my dear Martin Sleziak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any $x\in M$ belonged to every member of $Y,$ where $Y$ is an infinite subset of $X,$ then every nbhd $U$ of $X$ would have non-empty intersection with every member of $Y$ (because $x\in U\cap Z$ for all $Z\in Y$), implying that $X$ is not locally-finite.

A family $F$ of subsets of $M$ is called point-finite iff every $x\in M$ belongs to only finitely many members of $F.$ So a locally-finite family is point-finite. Point-finite is not equivalent to locally-finite. For example if $M=\mathbb R$ then $F=\{\{x\}:x\in M\}$ is point-finite but not locally-finite.

Comment: Subject reference : Meta-compact.